# Maven defining additional scope within module

Tags: java, maven, module, pom.xml

Say I have a module, let's call it "data". That module has packages a,b,c,d within it.

Is there anyway I can build "data" but only take packages a and b? Currently I am building a and b but then also including the entire "data" module as a dependency. The problem with this is that c and d also get included in that dependency. If I delete a class in package c, that class will still exist in the dependency. So instead of an error coming up when something in b tries to use that deleted class, it will compile because it now points to the existing one from the dependency.

Maybe it will help if I try to do what I want to do. Something like this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>blah</groupId>
        <artifactId>data</artifactId>
        <ignore-package>c</ignore-package>
        <ignore-package>d</ignore-package>
    </dependency>
```

So I get the data module but do not get the packages "c" or "d".

Comment: Can you elaborate more details..cause to honest I don't understand your problem..best would be an example project by which you describe your isse?

Comment: If you have a single maven project that builds a jar, then why you adding it as a dependency? if you have a,b,c,d as subprojects then you can exclude them

Comment: It sounds to me like your "module" is really 2 modules.  If you want to pluck code out of an artifact your artifact is too big.  

You probably need to create a parent POM and have a module for a&b and a module for c&d

Comment: @Terry, you are 100% correct. In an ideal world, I'd split these into two modules. But I do not have control over this so am looking for a work around.

Comment: I think you are out of luck.  You Almost want a maven exclude.  But an exclude works at the artifact level. Maven doesn’t really know about java classes.

Comment: @Terry Whoever is responsible for this module should clean it up for consumers...and of course we are not in an ideal world but if we find things which are wrong we fix them...

Comment: @Terry, Yeah, seems like it... Was hoping that Maven could do something really clever since it does build the jar so in theory, it shouldn't be too much trouble to ignore a directory when building it. 

In any case, I'm in the process of getting this split into two modules. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems like the best way, like Terry mentioned, is to split the modules. There's no better way (yet).